# Nodegit clone causes “No Content-Type header in response” error

Tags: node.js, git, gitlab, libgit2, nodegit

I'm having an issue with nodegit on CentOS 6.7. On our Windows development environment, I'm able to clone/push/pull from remote just fine using nodegit.

On CentOS, however, I get the following error on clone:

> No Content-Type header in response

We're not using Apache, just the standard GitLab rpm. GitLab is working fine on the CentOS box as well - I am able to pull and push successfully from Git Bash.  Unfortunately, I need to do this programmatically via nodegit, and it's not working.

I'd prefer to not have to resort to CURL if possible - nodegit really seemed like a more dignified option for my project.

It should be noted that I'm using basic HTTP user/password for authorization on our Gitlab instance, because:

- gitlab and all the programmatic git stuff is hidden on the server-side, and
- this is a proof of concept to see if a nodegit/gitlab solution is even feasible.

Here is the function that attempts the clone - it works great on Windows:

```
function pushUserUpdatesToGit(req, res, user, myItem, localPath) {
    var repo, index, oid, remote,
    userCreds = {
        credentials: function() {
            return nodegit.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew(user.username, user.pwd);
        }
    },
    authStuff = {
        remoteCallbacks: {
            credentials: userCreds.credentials,
            certificateCheck: function() { return 1;  }
        }
    };

    return nodegit.Clone.clone(myItem.GitLabRepoPath, localPath, authStuff)
        .then(function(theRepo) {
            repo = theRepo; // save it to reference in any callback we feel like
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Error cloning repo: " + err );
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
    ).then(function() {
        return repo.openIndex();
    }, function (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
    })
    // Some exciting stuff happens in here that I won't bore you all with
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR DOING GIT STUFF: " + error);
        return handleError(res, error);
    }).done(function() {
        console.log("done with git stuff");
        return res.json(200, myItem);
    });
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, you're running the same code on both systems; if so, have you compared the request/responses from each system to check for differences?

I don't quite get what you mean by going with curl. If you're using the Git protocol, you can't use curl to download the repository, and if you can, then libgit2 won't help you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you get this error because your git server response is not supporting the Smart HTTP (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP).

By default the nginx configuration of gitlab is supporting this. Are you by any chance running the included nginx setup of gitlab behind a reverse proxy?

If not and you are not using the included nginx setup from gitlab, this might help: https://gist.github.com/massar/9399764